# A static analyzer that can prove that some source code will never run under given circumstances

Tags: code-analysis, static-analysis, static-code-analysis

I am looking for a program or script or software library that can take some software sources:

```
// Module: ./myUtils
function hello(): void {
  console.log("Hello!");
}

// Module: ./userInput
function getUserInput(): number {
  /* Here something happens that cannot be known at build time */
}

// Module: ./main
import { hello } from "./myUtils";
import { getUserInput } from "./userInput";

if (getUserInput() === 42) {
  hello();
}
```

And additional knowledge such as:

```
getUserInput() === 42 will always be false
```

And determine that, under those circumstances:

- `hello()` will never be called.
- `./myUtils` can probably be removed altogether.

I am mainly interested in the TypeScript language but I am curious about this sort of code analyzer in general.